# Python: use regex to solve mathematical expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I was wondering if it was possible to use regex to solve simple mathematical expressions with real numbers, and the operators +, -, *, / and ^.

For example the input would be a string like '3.5+4^2' (this could also be written as '+3.5+4^2') and the output 19.5. My idea was to have regex first recognise ^ as the procedure to perform first. So he would take 4^2 and return 16 so the expression would be '3.5+16'. Then it would recognise + and return 19.5.

Another input example would be -4+5.5*4/2 --> -4+22/2 --> -4+11 --> 7

Comment: You may use `eval` function. `print eval('3.5+4**2') > 19.5`

Comment: I assume you just want to do this for fun. But the expressions aren't built from a regular grammar. You need a parser that supports context free grammars.

See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559763/regular-vs-context-free-grammars

Comment: @Valijon `eval` is a terrible solution unless you *really* know what you’re doing.

Answer (score 2):

Regular Expressions describe patterns on Strings, they cannot analyse Integers/Floats. Unless there is a very obscure hack to make it work (which I think is unlikely).

You can validate if a given string is a valid mathematical expression, but you cannot evaluate mathematical expressions using regexes.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions just *match*, they don't calculate. Therefore, it is perfectly fine to use regular expressions to match your string, akin to

```
>>> re.match(r'^(?P<n>[0-9]+)(?P<op>[-+\*/])(?P<rest>.+)$', '1+2+3').groupdict()
{'n': '1', 'op': '+', 'rest': '2+3'}
```

The actual calculation, however, is best performed in Python itself.

Comment: but can I use regex to extract the real number before and after ^, for example, evaluate that and then replace it in the string, until I get down to one number?

Comment: Sure, using `re.sub`. Instead of replacing strings, you can also first parse the whole tree of expressions and then evaluate it.

Comment: I've been trying to work this out for the last hour and didn't really get anywhere. Any chance you could help me out?

Comment: Maybe irrelevant, but probably you can answer..... if I change order ie. -+ to +-, the expression doesn't parse (I'm using re.compile btw).  Why so?

Comment: @0xc0de If a `-` is at the very start or at the very end of a character class, it denotes a literal `-` character. Otherwise, it means the range of characters, as in `0-6`, which is shorthand for `0123456`. Just like that, `[*-/]` is shorthand for `[*+,./-]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)
`^` can be replaced by `**` to get the proper formula.

```
>>> eval('3.5+4^2'.replace('^', '**'))
19.5
>>> eval('-4+5.5*4/2')
7.0
```

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval` instead of `eval` to avoid running malicious/dangerous code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a famouse notation you should use for this, the Polish notation [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation).

Regex won't help you a lot, because Regex use [graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) whereas the interpretation of the calcul line you want would use Threes.

You may be interested in threes, childs, leaf, rotate... behaviors.
This is very like a scool case, making this with the Polish notation, and with threes structure you will make this reading your line from left to right sequentially and without regex