# Regex skip in C++

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

This is my string:

```
/*
  Block1 {

    anythinghere
  }
*/

// Block2 { }
# Block3 { }

Block4 {

    anything here
}
```

I am using this regex to get each block name and inside content.

```
regex e(R"~((\w+)\s+\{([^}]+)\})~", std::regex::optimize);
```

But this regex gets all inside of description too. There is a “skip” option in PHP that you can use to skip all descriptions.

```
What_I_want_to_avoid(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|What_I_want_to_match
```

But this is C++ and I cannot use this skip method. What should I do to skip all descriptions and just get Block4 in C++ regex?

This regex detects `Block1`, `Block2`, `Block3` and `Block4` but I want to skip `Block1`, `Block2`, `Block3` and just get `Block4` (skip descriptions). How do I have to edit my regex to get just `Block4` (everything outside the descriptions)?

Comment: It looks like you try to accomplish something, using regular expressions, that should be accomplished by a parser. Having said that, it is not at all clear from your question what you actually want to match.

Comment: What do you mean by "skip all descriptions"? Are you trying not to match comments?

Comment: yes try to not match comments

Comment: You can skip the comments, but a note that `; Block3 { hi }` is invalid C++ if nothing exists before the first comment.

Comment: Do your language allow nested comments? Will the comment character inside strings count as comments (e.g. "tets/*test*/")? can block name and opening bracket be on each line?

Comment: Actually you have to not only parse comments, but parse strings outside of comments as well, if for example your strings could span lines.

Comment: could you edit my regex with what you said?

Comment: Be careful. In c++, `;` does not start a comment and neither does `#`. The `;` ends statements and `#` signals the preprocessor (as in `#include` statements). Comments in c++ either start with `//` or are surrounded by `/*` and `*/`.

Comment: _You can_ parse the blocks, _but_ the part between `{ ...}` can be subtly masked within a string like `{ ..."}";....}`. The way you would have to do it is match comments or strings or your block as a single expression, i.e. `comments|strings|(block{(?:comments|strings|.)*})` then look for capture group 1 to match. I could give you the regex, but it's very big.

Comment: please give me the full regex i'm confounded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you requested this long regex, here it is.

This will not handle *nested* Blocks like `block{ block{ } }`
it would match `block{ block{ }` } only.

Since you specified you are using C++11 as the engine, I didn't use
recursion. This is easily changed to use recursion say if you were to use
PCRE or Perl, or even BOOST::Regex. Let me know if you'd want to see that.

As it is it's flawed, but works for your sample.
Another thing it won't do is parse *Preprocessor Directives '#...'*  because
I forgot the rules for that (thought I did it recently, but can't find a record).

To use it, sit in a `while ( regex_search() )` loop looking for a match on
capture group 1, `if (m[1].success)` etc.. That will be your block.
The rest of the matches are for comments, quotes, or non-comments, unrelated
to the block. These have to be matched to progress the match position.

The code is *long* and redundant because there is no function calls (recursion)  in the C++11 EMCAscript. Like I said, use boost::regex or something.

**Benchmark**

Sample:

```
/*
  Block1 {

    anythinghere
  }
*/

// Block2 { }

Block4 {

   // CommentedBlock{ asdfasdf }
    anyth"}"ing here
}

Block5 {

   /* CommentedBlock{ asdfasdf }
    anyth}"ing here
   */
}
```

Results:

```
Regex1:   (?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\]|\\\n?)*?\n)|(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|(\w+\s*\{(?:(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\]|\\\n?)*?\n)|(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|(?!\})[\S\s][^}/"'\\]*))*\})|[\S\s](?:(?!\w+\s*\{(?:(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\]|\\\n?)*?\n)|(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|(?!\})[\S\s][^}/"'\\]*))*\})[^/"'\\])*)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   8
Elapsed Time:    1.95 s,   1947.26 ms,   1947261 µs
```

Regex Explained:

```
    # Raw:        (?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\]|\\\n?)*?\n)|(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|(\w+\s*\{(?:(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\]|\\\n?)*?\n)|(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|(?!\})[\S\s][^}/"'\\]*))*\})|[\S\s](?:(?!\w+\s*\{(?:(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\]|\\\n?)*?\n)|(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|(?!\})[\S\s][^}/"'\\]*))*\})[^/"'\\])*)
    # Stringed:  "(?:/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\\\]|\\\\\\n?)*?\\n)|(?:\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\[\\S\\s][^\"\\\\]*)*\"|'[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\[\\S\\s][^'\\\\]*)*'|(\\w+\\s*\\{(?:(?:/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\\\]|\\\\\\n?)*?\\n)|(?:\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\[\\S\\s][^\"\\\\]*)*\"|'[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\[\\S\\s][^'\\\\]*)*'|(?!\\})[\\S\\s][^}/\"'\\\\]*))*\\})|[\\S\\s](?:(?!\\w+\\s*\\{(?:(?:/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\\\]|\\\\\\n?)*?\\n)|(?:\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\[\\S\\s][^\"\\\\]*)*\"|'[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\[\\S\\s][^'\\\\]*)*'|(?!\\})[\\S\\s][^}/\"'\\\\]*))*\\})[^/\"'\\\\])*)"     


    (?:                              # Comments 
         /\*                              # Start /* .. */ comment
         [^*]* \*+
         (?: [^/*] [^*]* \*+ )*
         /                                # End /* .. */ comment
      |  
         //                               # Start // comment
         (?: [^\\] | \\ \n? )*?           # Possible line-continuation
         \n                               # End // comment
    )
 |                                 # OR,

    (?:                              # Non - comments 
         "
         [^"\\]*                          # Double quoted text
         (?: \\ [\S\s] [^"\\]* )*
         "
      |  '
         [^'\\]*                          # Single quoted text
         (?: \\ [\S\s] [^'\\]* )*
         ' 
      |  
         (                                # (1 start), BLOCK
              \w+ \s* \{               
              ####################
              (?:                              # ------------------------
                   (?:                              # Comments  inside a block
                        /\*                             
                        [^*]* \*+
                        (?: [^/*] [^*]* \*+ )*
                        /                                
                     |  
                        //                               
                        (?: [^\\] | \\ \n? )*?
                        \n                               
                   )
                |  
                   (?:                              # Non - comments inside a block
                        "
                        [^"\\]*                          
                        (?: \\ [\S\s] [^"\\]* )*
                        "
                     |  '
                        [^'\\]*                          
                        (?: \\ [\S\s] [^'\\]* )*
                        ' 
                     |  
                        (?! \} )
                        [\S\s]                          
                        [^}/"'\\]*                      
                   )
              )*                               # ------------------------
              #####################          
              \}                               
         )                                # (1 end), BLOCK

      |                                 # OR,

         [\S\s]                           # Any other char
         (?:                              # -------------------------
              (?!                              # ASSERT: Here, cannot be a BLOCK{ }
                   \w+ \s* \{                      
                   (?:                              # ==============================
                        (?:                              # Comments inside a block
                             /\*                              
                             [^*]* \*+
                             (?: [^/*] [^*]* \*+ )*
                             /                                
                          |  
                             //                               
                             (?: [^\\] | \\ \n? )*?
                             \n                               
                        )
                     |  
                        (?:                              # Non - comments inside a block
                             "
                             [^"\\]*                          
                             (?: \\ [\S\s] [^"\\]* )*
                             "
                          |  
                             '
                             [^'\\]*                          
                             (?: \\ [\S\s] [^'\\]* )*
                             ' 
                          |  
                             (?! \} )
                             [\S\s]                          
                             [^}/"'\\]*                       
                        )
                   )*                               # ==============================
                   \}                               
              )                                # ASSERT End

              [^/"'\\]                         # Char which doesn't start a comment, string, escape,
                                               # or line continuation (escape + newline)
         )*                               # -------------------------
    )                                # Done Non - comments
```

Answer (score 1):

Tl;DR: [Regular expressions cannot be used to parse full blown computer languages](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-beyond-regex/). What you want to do cannot be done with regular expressions. You need to develop a mini-C++ parser to filter out comments. [The answer to this related question might point you in the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503871/best-way-to-automatically-remove-comments-from-php-code).

Regex can be used to process [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), but computer languages such as C++, PHP, Java, C#, HTML, etc. have a more complex syntax that includes a property named "middle recursion". Middle recursion includes complications such as an arbitrary number of matching parenthesis, begin / end quotes, and comments that can contain symbols

If you want to understand this in more detail, [read the answers to this question about the difference between regular expressions and context free grammars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559763/regular-vs-context-free-grammars). If you are really curious, enroll in a [Formal Language Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language) class.