# What concepts or algorithms exist for parallelizing parsers?

Tags: algorithm, parsing, parallel-processing

It seems easy to parallelize parsers for large amounts of input data that is already given in a split format, e.g. a large list of individual database entries, or is easy to split by a fast preprocessing step, e.g. parsing the grammatical structure of sentences in large texts.

A bit harder seems to be parallel parsing that already requires quite some effort to locate sub-structures in a given input. Common programming language code looks like a good example. In languages like Haskell, that use layout/indentation for separating individual definitions, you could probably check the number of leading spaces of each line after you've found the start of a new definition, skip all lines until you find another definition and pass each skipped chunk to another thread for full parsing.

When it comes to languages like C, JavaScript etc., that use balanced braces to define scopes, the amount of work for doing the preprocessing would be much higher. You'd need to go through the whole input, thereby counting braces, taking care of text inside string literals and so on. Even worse with languages like XML, where you also need to keep track of tag names in the opening/closing tags.

I found [a parallel version of the CYK parsing algortihm](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7f00/907026e8ed51f46e3226134c111baf796a85.pdf) that seems to work for all context-free grammars. But I'm curious what other general concepts/algorithms do exist that make it possible to parallelize parsers, including such things as the brace counting described above which would only work for a limited set of languages. This question is not about specific implementations but the ideas such implementations are based on.

Comment: Given that most parsers spend a big part of their time on lexical analysis I doubt that one would see big gains in practical cases when finding substructures requires almost a full lexical analysis.

Comment: @Henry: yes, lexical analysis is something you must optimize. OTOH, if your (C++) compiler reads a million lines of text at optimized lexical speed, you still would probably like a factor of 8-32 speedup on your multicore system.  Yes, you still have to do full lexical analysis but you can still do that; read my answer on how McKeeman approached it.

Answer (score 8):

I think you will find McKeeman's 1982 paper on [Parallel LR Parsing](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~mckeeman/references/ParallelLR82.pdf) quite interesting, as it appears to be practical and applies to a broad class of grammars.

The basic scheme is standard LR parsing.  What is clever is that the (presumably long) input is divided into roughly N equal sized chunks (for N processors), and each chunk is parsed separately.  Because the starting point for a chunk may (must!) be in the middle of some of productions, McKeemans individual parsers, unlike classic LR parsers, start with all possible left contexts (requiring that the LR state machine be augmented) to determine which LR items apply to the chunk.   (It shouldn't take very many tokens before an individual parser has determined what states really apply, so this isn't very inefficient).  Then the results of all the parsers are stitched together.

He sort of ducks the problem of partitioning the input in the middle of a token. (You can imagine an arbitrarily big string literal containing text that looks like code, to fool the parser the starts in the middle).  What appears to happen is that parser runs into an error, and abandons its parse; the parser to its left takes up the slack.   One can imagine the chunk splitter to use a little bit of smarts to mostly avoid this.

He goes to demonstrate a real parser in which speedups are obtained.

Clever, indeed.

Comment: The link in the answer gives a 403 error

Comment: @saxbophone: Guess McKeeman must have retired.  I can no longer find that paper on the web.  However, you can visit http://scholar.google.com, and search for "Parallel Parsing" and get a wide variety of relevant papers.   Best of luck.