# get types of function

Tags: c#, string, parsing, types

I'm trying to parse this `expression` in C# like so:

```
fun(p1, p2, 33,"lina", g(x,5), ...)
```

How can I get the "type" of everything in the `expression`, given these examples:

```
fun    ---> function
p1, p2 ---> variables
33     ---> constant
"lina" ---> constant 
g      ---> function 
x      ---> variable
5      ---> constant
```

Comment: You cannot use regex to get **"type"** of string. You need some kind of parser to transform this string to some kind of data structure.

Comment: Can you please elaborate as the data you provided is insufficient to understand your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general case you *can't parse* such string with *regular expression*: regular expression can operate with *regular grammar* only (with some minor extensions), when you need *context free* one. You want a *parser* (e.g. [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) or [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/)). See

[Regular vs Context Free Grammars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559763/regular-vs-context-free-grammars)

for details. To show the difficulties you can face, let's just play with strings and comments:

```
 fun (1 + p1 + 1);                  // p1 is an argument
 fun (/*1 + p1 + 1*/);              // p1 is NOT an argument
 fun ("/*1" + p1 + "1*/");          // p1 is an argument 
 fun (/*"/*1" + p1 + "1*+/"*/);     // p1 is NOT an argument 
 fun ("/*""/*1" + p1 + "1*+/""*/"); // p1 is an argument  
 ...
```

Comment: is correct.  You need something more akin to an interpreter/parser than just a simple regex.

Comment: Ok, you posted what OP cannot do. But, would be better, imho, for OP, to suggest something, how he can solve his problem, probably in different way.

Comment: @tym32167: parsing is not an easy walk, but you're quite right: when stating that "X is not a solution", an aternative "Y can be used" should be provided. I can't see an easy way to marriage good old Lex/Yacc/Bison with .net, so I've mentioned Antlr and Irony